# Run Chrome in Windowed Kiosk Mode

Tags: windows, google-chrome, command-line

How can I run Chrome browser in Kiosk windowed mode (not app mode)? It's always fullscreen and I tried all `--disable-fullscreen` and `--disable-fullscreen-app` `--window-size` settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that is not possible, because that is one of the main features of the kiosk mode.
As far as I know kiosk mode mainly serves two purposes:

- fullscreen "pseudolock"
- browsing without any user data

Since you don't want the first, maybe --bswi (browse without sign in) might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try the application mode:

```
--app=file_url
```

Comment: It still allows F12 and has context menu... You need also `--force-app-mode` to disable that